# On click add and remove multiple classes on multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried looking around and could not find exactly what i need to do. Also not sure if there is a plugin that could do this the functions below:

I have built a site that is for two different photography studios e.g. Studio 01, Studio 02.
In the header on the right i have two  tags to switch between the two studios. Now originally i was going to have studio one repeated with different background images of the studio but it seems stupid as they have almost the same content besides background images. So instead when the user clicks on studio 02 then classes through out the page will be added and removed and thus background images can change etc.

So for more detail exactly what I need is: button 1 (Studio 01) is active on page load. When you click studio 02 button, button 1 becomes unactive and button two active. Then I need to add classes to different elements on the page and remove current classes on the page aswell. And this obviously needs to be work in reverse aswell so when you click back on studio 01 then the above happens again. Does this make sense?

I would like to provide code but it would be so much. For now the current site is here: dreamsynk.com/rosewater

Any help would be much appreciated, or even you anyone can direct me to a topic like this that has already been answered or a plugin i can use.

Comment: sure seems a lot simper to just have a master class on body tag to handle the css differences. `<body class="studio_1">`

Comment: I agree with @charlietfl. Using a class on the body will let you skip much js

Comment: Geese, how did i not think of that xD

Comment: You'll need Javascript (preferably JQuery). Look into `addClass()` and `removeClass()`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use AngularJS method ngShow, take a look in AngularJS.org

It's a very simple solution by Google Team.